# Check if a file exists in azure blob container

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have an azure blob container name "x" and I want to check if a file name "a.jpg" exists in that blob or not and return true or false based on that. It seems easy but there isn't a clear answer when I google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clearly mentioned in the document, if you are using c# you can use [`ExistsAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblob.existsasync?view=azure-dotnet-legacy#Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlob_ExistsAsync) method

```
public async Task<bool> FileExists(string fileName)
{
    return  await directory.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName).ExistsAsync();
}
```

Comment: Refer this sample https://github.com/nertilpoci/MultiStorageProvider/blob/c6e2ff9c68c58f2ff6b105499801ef02998a3572/MultiStorageProvider.Azure/Implementation/BlobStorageProvider.cs

Comment: If I may ask, how did you find this repo?

Comment: I don't remember now . Either i would have used as a reference or got the sample code at that moment. Is that your repo?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use REST Api if you want.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob-metadata

A lot more trouble... but works too.

> Request The Get Blob Metadata request may be constructed as follows.
>   HTTPS is recommended. Replace myaccount with the name of your storage
>   account:
>
> TABLE 1 GET or HEAD Method Request URI    HTTP Version
>   https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob?comp=metadata
>
> https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob?comp=metadata&snapshot=